# want to output the nested dictionary value

Tags: python

i am relatively new in python.I am working with the dictionary.In my dictionary there are two list values are inserted as below,

```
speed = ['20','30','25','50','40']
time = ['10','11','12','13','14']
dic = {'name':'Finder','details':'{ time : speed }'}
```

now i just want to get output just like that,

```
10:20
11:30
12:25
13:50
14:40
```

which associated with the
    time:speed
for that i write a for loop which is just like that,

```
for k,i in dic.items()
     print(k + ":" + i)
```

after executing the code i get an error which is just like that,

```
unhashable type list
```

is the error for the nested dictionary?? my another question is ,the for loop i write ,is it the perfect to get the output of the nested dictionary value??

please help me to fix these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use list as the dictionary key.

```
>>> speed = ['20','30','25','50','40']
>>> time = ['10','11','12','13','14']
>>> {time: speed}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Convert the list to tuple to use it as key.

```
>>> {tuple(time): speed}
{('10', '11', '12', '13', '14'): ['20', '30', '25', '50', '40']}
```

And you **don't need to use dictionary** to get the desired output.

Using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> speed = ['20','30','25','50','40']
>>> time = ['10','11','12','13','14']
>>> for t, s in zip(time, speed):
...     print('{}:{}'.format(t, s))
...
10:20
11:30
12:25
13:50
14:40
```

Comment: But converting it to a tuple would be problematic as well, there would be no _real_ benefits.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, What do you mean for *problematic*?

Comment: Well if you were to make it a tuple, then you would again need to iterate over the tuple _and_ the key at the same time for each element. Is it not better to have them as separate dicts instead?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, I just wanted to tell OP that he/she cannot use list as the key, but tuple. And as you can see, I doesn't use dictionary to get the OP's desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use a dictionary comprehension, and use `zip` to combine the two. The problem you are having is this, you are using a `list` as a dictionary key, and that is not possible, because a `list` is unhashable. SO for your example:

```
speed = ['20', '30', '25', '50', '40']
time = ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14']

for key, value in zip(time, speed):
    print key, ":", value


print

# Or you could have a dictionary comprehension, to make it
d = {key: value for key, value in zip(time, speed)}

for key, value in d.items():
    print key, ":", value
```

### Output

```
10 : 20
11 : 30
12 : 25
13 : 50
14 : 40

11 : 30
10 : 20
13 : 50
12 : 25
14 : 40
```

Comment: I would rather use `dict(zip(time, speed))` instead of dict comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
speed = ['20','30','25','50','40']
time = ['10','11','12','13','14']
dic = {'name':'Finder','details':'{ time : speed }'}

l1,l2 = [locals()[x.strip("{} ")] 
        for x in dic['details'].split(":")]

for p in zip(l1, l2):
    print ":".join(p)
```

Gives:

```
10:20
11:30
12:25
13:50
14:40
```